# Error in firebase-admin on Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, access-token, firebase-admin

I need to use `firebase-admin` to create a token to authenticate in firebase (have another way?). But when I try to use, I receive the error that `jsonwebtoken` module is not found, then I install this module. After, I this, I receive the error `node-purge` module not found, then I install this. And the two error is fixed, but appears a third: `cannot read property map of null`.

What I do? Have another way to make tokens for firebase?

Answer (score 0):

`firebase-admin` is a SDK supposed to be working server-side. Take a look at the [AngularFire2 library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to use Firebase client-side

Comment: I use `angularfire2` too. But I need to create an Token to auth and the way that I found was using `firebase-admin`. You know a possible way to do this using `angularfire2`?

Comment: Yes I've used it in a project, it's in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: The problem is that `AngularFireAuth`  have _signInWithCustomToken_ method but not _createCustomToken_ :(